# How can I improve the relationship between the designer and developers?

Tags: design, agile, user-interface, reactjs

My team is faced with a big challenge.  We are building a greenfield app against a legacy codebase.  The legacy code contains .NET controls with a certain look and feel.  Our front end is ReactJS.  We are tasked with reproducing the look and feel of these legacy controls.  The designer is tasked with creating Mockups, which are essentially controls that look and feel like the legacy system.  Sometimes she will point us to the legacy system itself, other times mockups.  In either case, we have to reverse engineer the CSS and JS to try and get close enough to the look and feel that the end user can't tell the difference between the ReactJS control and the .NET control.

The designers and developers are at an impasse.  The developers want CSS from the designer.  The designer insists that the developers do not need the CSS and the designer simply doesn't have time to provide it.  Reverse engineering should be sufficient.  The developers, including myself, miss key details, like column alignment, spacing around text boxes and other things that developers, at least my team and me, just don't notice.  The designer is getting irritated that developers do not notice key design details.

The team is feeling demoralized.  The designer has been negative in her comments and attitude.  She talked down to the developers and took no responsibility for the issues at hand.  She is trying to place a strict and severe process onto the developer workflow that I fear will seriously inhibit progress and possibly cause developer turnover.  The development team feels this is a case of GIGO.

Surely the developers can find better ways to build the UI.  However, there are also problems with the acceptance criteria, mockups are sometimes just a wireframe with no style detail and the legacy system we reference is inconsistent.  UX is playing hard ball and discounts all these issues.

In summary, is it asking too much from the designer to get CSS specs?  Is it pretty standard in the community to reverse engineer controls in this fashion?  Do you have any suggestions to help this team work together and get along?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a workplace issue than a software engineering problem. The question might be more suited for [workplace.se]

Comment: Maybe find a middle way, as supplying css by a designer also isn't a holy grail. Try to make a list of common elements and discuss openly how they should look. That way you can get consistently same results without having to repeat the same discussions on each view. A bit like bootstrap. Together build a library and common language to cooperate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answers are not useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem is communication.  Some key developers are located in another state and their input has been difficult to come by.  I decided to bring on one of these remote developers to the UI work.  Immediately we began to discover holes in the information such as there is a legacy convention to use bootstrap classes to achieve a flow layout (row-fluid).  I also plan to take advantage of the fact the remote developer sits right next to the designer so they can coordinate together.

My mistake with the designer was trying to communicate an emotional problem over Slack as opposed to video chat (in person when possible).  I made a similar mistake when I again posted a text message on this forum when the issue covers feelings.  Again, I failed to get my point across.  I also plan to have a personal phone call with the designer and explain to her how I feel.  I will explain how the response made me feel personally.  I will explain how calling a developer blind or implying they are stupid is not necessary in order to get her point across.  I do empathize with her in that we have some challenges to overcome and let's work together to find out how we can best address them.

Comment: Ultimately I blame people here.  This issue was never resolved and I'm glad to not be there anymore. Like it or not, bad jobs exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic "push the work around" behavior.

You've already tipped your hand in the title where you label the designer as not being a team player.

I'll do to you what I do when my friends complain to me about their marriage.  I'll ask you to see it from the other side.

The designers job is to provide mockups that ensure CONSISTENCY of look and feel.  It's not to tell you how the CSS should look.

The designer would be perfectly justified in shooting down anything you create that isn't a pixel perfect reproduction of the mock up.  There actually are [visual regression testing tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+CSS+Regression+Testing&oq=Visual+CSS+Regression+Testing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64j69i60j69i61.3015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that can turn that requirement into an automated test.

That said if I was talking to the designer I wouldn't point any of this out.  I'd encourage finding the most effective and least painful way to ensure CONSISTENCY.  If tossing out some CSS that you aren't required to create helps that happen faster than fine.

The problem here isn't that someone is right and someone is wrong.  It's that selfishness has set in on both sides.  A marriage isn't a 50-50 thing.  You each have to give more than your fair half or something always comes up short.

This includes the one whose job it is to get all these people to work together. ;)

Comment: I called out the designer in this case specifically because the designer's attitude has been "it's your problem and I'm not gonna change a thing".  She's been negative and demoralizing for the team to deal with.  I spoke to her asking for a simple attitude adjustment while still getting her point across and so far have no response.  I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: She's a tester. It's her job to be negative. You're trying to make her do a developer's job as well. That compromises her integrity. Her attitude may stink but it sounds to me like she's surrounded by people who don't respect her job. I treat my testers like my career depends on it.  Because it does.  Testers tell you "no" when the "no" costs you hours not months. Testers deserve respect.

Comment: Respect should go both ways my friend.

Comment: True. When it doesn't remember the only one you have control of is yourself.  I can't talk to her. I can talk to you.  And you haven't once shown me that you have concern for anything other than the work this is causing you.  If that's what you show her I can understand why her attitude stinks.  You seem to be ignoring any solution other than getting her to do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see your point.  Where in your answer are you explaining how the team can compromise?  I hear you saying that the team should compromise, but paradoxically that the designer is correct.

Comment: Where do I call for compromise? p1s1. p3s2. p6s2&3 (which you ignored just now), all of paragraph 7 and I suppose 8. As long as you think this is about who is correct and who is not, you're just not going to understand. If you just want someone to listen to you and take your side go talk to a bartender.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey sorry to intervene, but as an outsider of this discussion i can only observe that your last comment only confirms CandleOrange's comment: you are quick to ignore any solution that doesn't comply with your own view. This is not a coaching site: either questions/answers are objective (on methodology) or the question is out of scope (i.e. Office politics or primarily opinion based)